# Bool Methods in C#

Tags: c#, boolean

I want a WinFormApp to calculate the Prime numbers between 100 to 1000 and display them in a "lb" list box. But I'm facing with this error:

> WinFormApp1.Form1.pn(int)': not all code paths return a value

```
bool pn(int n)
{
    for (int j = 2; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if (n % j != 0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 100; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        if (pn(i) == true)
            lb.Items.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you follow the logic, in the case that you call pn(1) it won't know what to return

Comment: This may be a time where using braces in all instances would help show the logic to prevent this mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply placed your `return true` inside the loop by mistake. As well as giving incorrect results, it the compiler can see that if the loop finishes, there'll be no value returned, hence the compile error.

```
bool pn(int n)
{
    for (int j = 2; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if (n % j != 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bool pn(int n)
{
    for (int j = 2; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if (n % j == 0)
         {
              return false;
         }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That is wrong from what the question is about, also, that code is illogical. So if `n % j` isn't `0` then return true? That renders the for-loop useless, could just have `int j = 2` and check for it. Which only checks if the number is even.